# How to Make .py scrape on timer and relay to HTML page?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I can get the program to scrape perfectly and display on my html page `home.html`. I now want it to run the scrape every minute. I have the code for the html page to refresh automatically (checked and works) to pull the new data.

Tried (included the commented out lines and indent properly) and got this error when running in the debug when I try to load the html page:

> return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
> TypeError: home() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

. I believe I am having an issue passing the `data` variable at the end of my scrape into the `home()` function to have it translate to the `home.html` file.

**Note**: When the scrape works perfectly -- the scraping code is not in a function, and I do not include `data` within the parenthesis of the `home()` function.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

# def scrape():
url = 'https://www.espn.com/golf/leaderboard/_/tournamentId/401465506'
req = requests.get(url)
bsObj=BeautifulSoup(req.text,'lxml')

data = bsObj.find_all('div', class_ = 'Table__Scroller')

table_data=[]
tablerows=bsObj.select('table tr')

for tr in tablerows[1:]:
    row=[]
    for t in tr.select('td')[1:4]:
        row.extend([t.text.strip()])
    table_data.append(row)
data=table_data
   # return data


@app.route('/')
def home(data):
    return render_template('home.html', data=data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
    # while True:
    #     scrape()
    #     home()
    #     time_wait = 1
    #     time.sleep(time_wait * 60)
```

Comment: "...got an error when running in the env..." Please [edit] your question to include the full error traceback, as that has valuable information to help understand the problem

Comment: Usually a web page won't update until the user refreshes their browser.

Comment: @MarkRansom there's code that refreshes the webpage. That isn't the issue. I have the html refresh on its own already. I need the .py file to scrape the data every so often. I watched a video online where the guy does it by wrapping it in a function (like I tried above) but he doesn't have it going to a html which is my home function that is causing the issue